# Crystal Reports Leaving out parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, report, selection, record

I have a crystal report that I am modifying the record selection formula. I have a parameter "Inventory_Class" that can have 3 values 0, 1 or 2. If set to 1 I want my DB field "NON_Controllable" that is binary field to select all False records, if the parameter is set to 2 then I want all True records but if the incoming parameter is set to 0 then I don't want to filter on the DB field "NON_Controllable" at all. I can get formula to work when parameter is set to 1 and 2 selecting Non_Controllable false and true records but when the parameter is set to 0 my report returns no records when it should be returning all records.

```
{Inventory_Catalog.PROP_NO} = {?PROPERTY} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_TYPE_CD} = {?TYPE} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.OPER_BUS_SEG_CD} = {?OPER_BUS_SEG} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SURP} = {?SURP} and
{Inventory_Catalog.COND_CD} = {?CONDITION} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_ID} = {?INVEN_ID} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SER_NO} = {?SERIAL} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.BUS_UNIT_CD} = {?BUS_UNIT_CD} and
IF ({?INVENTORY_CLASS} = 1) THEN
    {Inventory_Cat_Header.NON_CONTROLLABLE} = FALSE
ELSE IF ({?INVENTORY_CLASS} = 2) THEN
    {Inventory_Cat_Header.NON_CONTROLLABLE} = TRUE
ELSE IF ({?INVENTORY_CLASS} = 0) THEN
    NOT {Inventory_Cat_Header.NON_CONTROLLABLE}
```

How can I modify this formula to work?

Comment: Where is your `else` statement

Answer (score 0):

you can try passing the parameters for each conditions instead.

```
IF 
({?INVENTORY_CLASS} = 1) THEN
{Inventory_Cat_Header.NON_CONTROLLABLE} = FALSE and 
{Inventory_Catalog.PROP_NO} = {?PROPERTY} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_TYPE_CD} = {?TYPE} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.OPER_BUS_SEG_CD} = {?OPER_BUS_SEG} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SURP} = {?SURP} and
{Inventory_Catalog.COND_CD} = {?CONDITION} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_ID} = {?INVEN_ID} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SER_NO} = {?SERIAL} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.BUS_UNIT_CD} = {?BUS_UNIT_CD}
ELSE IF 
({?INVENTORY_CLASS} = 2) THEN
{Inventory_Cat_Header.NON_CONTROLLABLE} = TRUE and 
{Inventory_Catalog.PROP_NO} = {?PROPERTY} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_TYPE_CD} = {?TYPE} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.OPER_BUS_SEG_CD} = {?OPER_BUS_SEG} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SURP} = {?SURP} and
{Inventory_Catalog.COND_CD} = {?CONDITION} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_ID} = {?INVEN_ID} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SER_NO} = {?SERIAL} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.BUS_UNIT_CD} = {?BUS_UNIT_CD}
else 
{Inventory_Catalog.PROP_NO} = {?PROPERTY} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_TYPE_CD} = {?TYPE} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.OPER_BUS_SEG_CD} = {?OPER_BUS_SEG} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SURP} = {?SURP} and
{Inventory_Catalog.COND_CD} = {?CONDITION} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.INVEN_ID} = {?INVEN_ID} and
{Inventory_Catalog.SER_NO} = {?SERIAL} and
{Inventory_Cat_Header.BUS_UNIT_CD} = {?BUS_UNIT_CD}
```